# How to add plugins to Pretzel?

Tags: .net, plugins, static-site, pretzel

I'm looking to set up a lightweight CMS for a client and I've been looking into Jekyll + Prose.io and Pretzel.

Since we run Windows servers and all of our existing data code is in .net, we're leaning towards using Pretzel. However, I have found some really useful looking plugins for Jekyll, and then began investigating if there were anything similar for Pretzel.

Unfortunately, the only info I can find is from some comments on the Pretzel issues on github, that you drop a dll with the right overrides in it into the _plugins folder.

Anyone know if there is a listing or a how to anywhere?

thanks,
Marcel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **how to** is planned but sadly not written right now.

Nevertheless, to make a plugin you need to create a new .net library project, reference Pretzel.exe and implement an interface from the [Pretzel Extensibility folder](https://github.com/Code52/pretzel/tree/master/src/Pretzel.Logic/Extensibility).
You have some example of the usage of the interfaces in the code source of Pretzel or on existing plugins (https://github.com/thoemmi/Pretzel.RedirectFrom, https://github.com/thoemmi/Pretzel.Sitemap).

You can still have some [problems](https://github.com/Code52/pretzel/issues/266) while developing a plugin but the next version will be plugin friendly and will even accept [ScriptCs plugins](https://github.com/Code52/pretzel/pull/229) :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The client has decided to go with Kentico for their CMS, which is too bad because I was really hoping to get to build one using a static html generator. I will definitely keep Pretzel (and Jekyll) in mind for future projects though, as the whole idea of a minimalist CMS is really appealing.